# Docker doesn't see static updates on Django project

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, static

Until today, Docker had been successfully receiving my static updates. However, today, when I attempted to change my logo, nothing happened. Additionally, when I modified some CSS styles, I encountered the same issue. I tried running "python manage.py collectstatic," but it didn't resolve the problem.

It's possible that Docker is not copying static files to the app directory anymore. But why? Until today, this process was functioning properly.

This is my Dockerfile

```
enter code here

FROM python:3.11.4
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=adanetsite.settings
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gettext
RUN apt-get install -y locales locales-all
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
EXPOSE 8080
# CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn_config.py", "adanetsite.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example including your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Do you have a Compose setup that tries to share files to a reverse proxy using a named volume?  The contents of the named volume never update, and the old content there will hide any changes in the image.

Comment: I shared my Dockerfile

Comment: I controlled. Docker doesn't copy static updates to app folder but I don't understand why

Comment: I don't see anything that collects or serves static files. You might be using the development server which can serve static files, but it's not suitable for deployment. typically there's a 2nd container running a web server to serve static files.